# How can a <dl> be styled to have <dt> and <dd> in columns of relative width?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Using zurb's foundation it's simple to style forms with variable columns width using divs. I need to do the same using dl, e.g.:
- have dt to expand two columns in the zurb grid (16.7%)
- have all dd's of the list fill the remaining 10 columns (83.3%)

I've found solutions with fixed-width columns using padding and margin, nesting a second dl without dt inside the parent's dd.
The currently preferred, last alternative I've found just doubles the dl:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
        <dl class="sub-nav" input-radio>
            <dt>Scope:</dt>
        </dl>
    </div><!-- col -->
    <div class="small-10 columns">
        <dl class="sub-nav" input-radio>
            <dd class="active"><a href="engine" value="videodb">videoDB</a></dd>
            <dd><a href="engine" value="imdb">IMDB</a></dd>
            <dd><a href="engine" value="amazon">Amazon</a></dd>
        </dl>
    </div><!-- col -->
</div><!-- row -->
```

Is there a variable-width solution without need for nested dls?

Comment: Yes, probably; do you have any relevant/[sscce](http://sscce.org/) HTML/CSS to share? Perhaps a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could play with? Help *us* to help *you*; make it *easy* for us to help you.

Comment: Example added- works by doubling the dl and splitting dt from dds..